solana public node das api
I am looking to run solaana node, with digital assets standard api component, but wanted to understand how is public node setup to provide the api methods, what plugin/components are used for setting up node with this das

check out the repo https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/digital-asset-rpc-infrastructure
